# Libgdx Demo Cuboc

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to set up the cuboc demo and when I loaded everything up I get the error Cannot instantiate the type ImmediateModeRenderer for the following line.

```
ImmediateModeRenderer renderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer(2000*2);
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

I have added the appropriate jar files to the build path.

Comment: solved... just needed to change to ImmediateModeRenderer10

Answer (score 0):

You have just to change ImmediateModeRenderer 10-